# Find the value of $x$ in the triangle below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Given the triangle below, where $AB = BC$, find the value of $x$ (Answer: $150^o$)

[image]

My progress:

[image]

$2\alpha+a+2\theta = 90^o\implies (\alpha+\theta) = 45^o - \frac{a}{2}\\
\alpha+b + 2\theta = 90^o\\\
\alpha+b = a+2\alpha \implies \alpha = b-a\\
x=180^0-(\alpha+\theta)=135^o +\frac{a}{2}\\
180-(3\theta+2\alpha)+180-(a+b)+x = 360 \implies x = 3\theta+2\alpha+a+b\\
$

Some detail is missing

[image]

It is not possible to change the solution and get the original figure

Comment: In the bottom figure, you have it the wrong way around compared to the upper two figures. In the original figure, the left side bottom angle $\angle BAK=2\alpha$ and the right bottom angle $\angle BCK=\alpha$, but you've put what seems to be $\alpha=10$ on the left and $2\alpha=20$ on the right.

Comment: I changed the drawing, maybe you understand better..If you change the angles the 3 segments do not intersect in $K$

Comment: Thanks for fixing your diagram. It clearly is an isoceles triangle with those numbers. Assuming the diagram is correct, it seems there is something we've overlooked. I'll leave my answer as is for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I use $t,a$ instead of $\theta$, $\alpha$ for ease of typing.)

[image: math stackexchange 4467868 find angle in picture]

In the picture, $E$ is the mid point of $AC$. A prime denotes reflection w.r.t. $BE$, so for instance $A'=C$. Build $K'$, then $L=AK\cap A'K'\in BE$. Divide the $4t$ angle in $\hat B$ in four $t$-parts, the angles $\widehat{KAB}$, $\widehat{K'CB}$ in two $a$-parts. Draw all remaining angle bisectors in $\Delta BAL$ and $\Delta BCL$. Denote by $u$ the half angles built in $L$ in these triangles. The sum of angles in them is $180^\circ$, so
$$
a+t+u=\frac 12180^\circ=90^\circ\ .
$$
Since $KK'\|AA'=AC$ is perpendicular to $BLE$, we have two $(a+t)$-angles in $\Delta LKK'$, they are then copied in $\Delta LAC$.
The sum of angles in $\Delta ABC$ is $180^\circ$ so:
$$
180^\circ=4t+(2a+(a+t))+(2a+(a+t))=6(a+t)\ .
$$
This gives $a+t=30^\circ$, so the angle in $K$ in $\Delta BKC$ is the remaining amount of $180^\circ$.

$\square$

Comment: You found the missing link, well done.

Comment: Thanks for the resolution. I posted another way of solving

Answer (score 1):

$\angle PBC = \frac{\angle ABC}{2} =2θ\\
 \angle PCB= 2\alpha ( by ~symmetry)\\
 \triangle  BPC : K (incenter) \implies  \angle CPK= \angle KPB(I)\\
 \angle APH= \angle KPB(o.b.v.)(II)\\
\angle APH= \angle HPC(III)\\
 (De (I),(II)e(III)\angle KPB=\angle CPK= \angle HPC
\therefore \angle KPB=\angle CPK=\angle HPC=60^o\\
\triangle  BPC: 2θ+2α+120^o=180^o \implies θ+α=30\\
\triangle BKC: x=\angle BKC=180^o−(θ+α)=150^o$

[image]